# Is localStorage fully loaded only after DOM is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have got a bug with some javascript code that it's hard to reproduce (so no jsfiddle, sorry). Exactly the same browser (FF 37.0.2), but two different machines, and I can only reproduce the bug on one of them.

I suspect the issue has something to do with localStorage and the fact that I check if an item is there outside $(document).ready().

Is that required? Do I need to wait for the DOM to be ready before reliably accessing localStorage? Is my hypothesis plausible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

localStorage is not something that needs to be "loaded" asynchronously.  It is available the moment the page starts to load and can be used by Javascript anywhere in the page.  If the browser has to fetch values form somewhere (e.g. the disk), that is done synchronously when you request the data or before.

There is no need to wait with `$(document).ready()` before accessing localStorage.  The cause of your issue must be something else.

FYI, you can read the spec on WebStorage here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-localstorage.  There is no indication in the localStorage section of that document that JS code must "wait" before accessing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't mean that it's required by the specification, but is it possible that Firefox handles it that way? I was brought to that hypothesis by this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13856156/825190

Comment: @Alessandro - I can't tell you if Firefox has a bug in how localStorage works or not (though it's an old feature that has been around a long time so I rather doubt it), but it is not supposed to require waiting for the DOM to load.  In fact, localStorage has nothing to do with the DOM at all - it's a completely separate entity, read from a different place, etc....