# How to use localStorage in Cordova mobile app?

Tags: html, cordova, mobile, local-storage

Please I developed my mobile app and is primarily using localStorage for storing account info and some other info. The app has mobile and browser version.

For the browser version, I expect a user that is logged in to not be redirected to an auth page on browser restart. This works fine as my info are stored in localStorage. On the other hand, my mobile doesn't. User have to log in whenever he restart the app.

Please what option do I have? What option do developers use for the mobile storage? Do I have to use database? If so which one should use and where can I find a better documentation on this topic?

*Note: I am using Cordova for my mobile app development framework.*

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("variable", value);`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, localStorage is tied to browser history. Some mobile browsers have an option to erase browser history on exit. If that box has a checkmark in it, then localStorage gets purged along with browser history everytime the browser is closed! So, you can ask the user to go into Settings and uncheck that box. Note: localStorage is not supported by older IE browsers, Opera Mini, and some Blackberry devices.

If cookies are enabled, you could use a one-time cookie code to log the user in automatically, but that cookie must expire after first use. Once the user is logged in, the server must issue a new cookie code to the client. And the client can use that new cookie to log in once again or keep alive the session. Using the same cookie twice should not work for security reasons. And the server must make sure never to issue the same code to two different users!

I remember, about 10 yrs ago, I went online to check my emails, and immediately the site had me logged into another user's account! I could have read that person's private emails and stuff, but I decided not to. I reported the incident to the admin. The problem was probably their server issued a random quick-login access code to me, and another user somehow got the same access code that I got. And when I opened the website, it thought that I was that other person. If your site deals with money and credit cards, you should avoid this technique! Any kind of auto login is a bad idea for a bank!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plug-in to store data in an SQLite database using Cordova [in this link](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)
. You can find more details about storage with Cordova [in the doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html).

Comment: why doesn't my localStorage works at the moment ? Does that mean my only choice is to use db ?

Comment: I can't tell, you should explain your issue with local storage, or  maybe post some code, local storage should work on all platforms supported by Corodva as mentioned in the doc

Comment: This is a bit of complicated process. Installing plugins do not let you to the output very fast.

Comment: I'm using this plug-in with Cordova/PhoneGap and its working very nicely, you can install it like this : `cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save`, good luck anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Save your data by using the following:

```
localStorage.setItem("variable", value);
```

Retrieve it from localstorage by using the following:

```
localStorage.getItem("variable");
```

It is as simple as it is.
Reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: @G I am doing the same thing actually, but outside the deviceready events. IT does not persist.

Comment: why do you need it outside of the deviceready events? You might want them in your `this.platform.ready().then(() => {}` only ryt?

Comment: [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30009046/4340139) This one will solve your doubt I hope :) @NuruSalihu

Comment: @G my app is a hybrid app built in react js . Everything is done and compile by webpack. The whole thing is just reference in index.html