# What causes Firefox to clear localStorage on reload in private mode

Tags: firefox, local-storage

I use a private browsing window to test my webapp with a blank slate.
If I close the page and reopen it localStorage is reset, as expected.

However, when I refresh the page, usually localStorage persists, but sometimes it is reset.
I'd be fine with either behavior, but the unpredictability is slowly driving me insane. Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Probably your code is persisting initial state.

Comment: Might be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852209/localstorage-unreliable-in-firefox

Comment: I withdraw my comment. I'm still seeing it even after I try the localStorage.length trick. Let me know if you find the answer.